# Wix installer notify progress to C# application

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3.6

What I want exactly to handle, is a WPF application that is able to communicate with an .msi generated with WiX.

- How can I let the WPF application know what the .msi package is doing at every moment, get the progress of the installation, and draw that progress in a WPF progress bar that substitutes the WiX one.
- If this part is possible, is there any way to enable/disable any feature from the WPF application to the .msi package?

I don't need the exact code, only a general idea on if this is possible or not!

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:** I'm using [this link](http://www.wrightfully.com/part-1-of-writing-your-own-net-based-installer-with-wix-overview/) as reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.  There's a sample of how to do it in the wix source tree (WPF external UI handler)   If you want to create a WiX Burn Bootstrapper Application in WPF you can checkout this project also:

http://wixwpf.codeplex.com/

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I was looking for. A clear starting point! :)